# How to configure gmail to send a GET request to my API, after receiving a new e-mail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

Actualy, what I want to do, is to make gmail execute a GET request to my API, after receiving any e-mail in the mailbox. Is there a way to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Look at the watch command in the gmail API at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch.
This sets up a a push notification watch on the given user mailbox, provided of course that you have permission to access the mailbox.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of services, like https://ifttt.com/ or https://zapier.com/ that can trigger events (such as 'call an api') when you get a new email.

Comment: thnks for ur reply, i'll try those services (y)

Comment: seems it's removed now

https://help.ifttt.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020249393-Important-update-about-the-Gmail-service

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a program to manage your Gmail account and code handlings for when a new email arrives.

I can give you a small example.

Using Python you could setup and install `imapclient`. Using this you can interact with your Gmail account `pip imapclient`***You will need to disable two-factor authentication for this!***

Now, using the code example over at [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-e-mail-notifier-using-leds/python-script) you can see how to interact and do something whena  new mail arrives into your account.

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python
>
> from imapclient import IMAPClient
> import time
>
> import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
>
> DEBUG = True
>
> HOSTNAME = 'imap.gmail.com'
> USERNAME = 'your username here'
> PASSWORD = 'your password here'
> MAILBOX = 'Inbox'
>
> NEWMAIL_OFFSET = 1   # my unread messages never goes to zero, yours might
> MAIL_CHECK_FREQ = 60 # check mail every 60 seconds
>
> GPIO.setwarnings(False)
> GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
> GREEN_LED = 18
> RED_LED = 23
> GPIO.setup(GREEN_LED, GPIO.OUT)
> GPIO.setup(RED_LED, GPIO.OUT)
>
> def loop():
>     server = IMAPClient(HOSTNAME, use_uid=True, ssl=True)
>     server.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
>
>     if DEBUG:
>         print('Logging in as ' + USERNAME)
>         select_info = server.select_folder(MAILBOX)
>         print('%d messages in INBOX' % select_info['EXISTS'])
>
>     folder_status = server.folder_status(MAILBOX, 'UNSEEN')
>     newmails = int(folder_status['UNSEEN'])
>
>     if DEBUG:
>         print "You have", newmails, "new emails!"
>
>     if newmails > NEWMAIL_OFFSET:
>         GPIO.output(GREEN_LED, True)
>         GPIO.output(RED_LED, False)
>     else:
>         GPIO.output(GREEN_LED, False)
>         GPIO.output(RED_LED, True)
>
>     time.sleep(MAIL_CHECK_FREQ)
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     try:
>         print 'Press Ctrl-C to quit.'
>         while True:
>             loop()
>     finally:
>         GPIO.cleanup()
> ```

Now, instead of the GPIO/Raspberry pi actions, you can carry out a get request! This can be achived using the `urllib2` library with one line.

Comment: thanks for ur reply, well the api that i want to call actualy does this work, it uses an imap-php client to get the new received email, what i'm trying to do is configure gmail to execute this code if a new email is recieved